# Replacing my current Linq OrderBy with Dynamic Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my action methods to OrderBy my data:-

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
{
    vm = repository.FindVMs(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialSerial).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
}
else if(sort == "server_desc")
{
    vm = repository.FindVMs(withOutSpace).OrderByDescending(a => a.ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
    ViewBag.ServerSortPam = "server_ans";
}
else 
{
    vm = repository.FindVMs(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
    ViewBag.ServerSortPam = "server_desc";
}
```

I have installed `Linq.Dynamics` , but I am not sure how I can replace my current code to use dynamic linq queries , so that I do not have to manually write separate orderBY statements for the different sort parameters.?

Mainly to make “`OrderByDescending(a => a.ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial)`” & “`OrderBy(a => a.ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial)`” dynamically generated based on the passed parameter instead of having to write two different linq queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The OrderBy and OrderByDecending clauses would look something like this using dynamic linq:

```
OrderBy("ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial")
```

and

```
OrderBy("ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial DESC").
```

If you want to get rid of the extra if statements, it might be helpful to pass a flag instead of a string value.  For example:

```
IQueryable<SomeEntityType> ApplySort(IQueryable<SomeEntityType> query, bool? sortByPartialAsc)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("ITServer.Technology.PartialSerial");

    if (sortByPartialAsc == false) sb.Append(" DESC");

    return query.OrderBy(sb.ToString());
}
```

Depending on how your view model generates your sort parameter, this method may need some tweaking, but you should get the idea.

I've been keeping Dynamic Linq up-to-date in case you're interested. 
https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic